# Visually disabled and chess

Tags: learning

I am very curious as I have seen many of them playing: How do visually disabled people learn chess? And what are all the types of equipment they use to learn the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are chess sets made for the visually impaired.  They are called 'tactile' chess sets.  The game is played by touch. The pieces lock into the board.  Removing a lock constitutes "touch move".

Here's an example, though I am not sure it is a 'tournament quality' tactile set.

[image]